# SQL Server dates are converted to date/time in Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a database in SQL Server that also has a related tabular database in Analysis Server. One of the tables has columns of type `date` in SQL Server:

[image]

If I run a SQL select in SQL Server `select * from app_dates` , I get the dates:

[image]

But if I run the equivalent in DAX `evaluate app_dates` I get date/time values instead of dates:

[image]

The problem is that my program detects automatically the types, and the type that Analysis Services returns is date/time instead of date.

How to tell Analysis Services that the column type should be `date` ?

Comment: I don't think DAX has access to a date-only data type.

Comment: you are right https://dax.guide/datatypes/

Comment: @ps0604 you can change the Data Format in a Tabular Model to achieve the  MM/dd/yyyy format you are looking for without the time included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the data type and data format of that column in your SSAS model. You can do this by viewing the properties of the column. I have an example below how to get the MM/DD/yyyy format you want without the time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/column-properties-ssas-tabular?view=asallproducts-allversions

[image: MMddyyyy example]